# Groups.Add Disconnect

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I am using Signalr (latest version) and a call to Groups.Add (adding around 30 groups to a single connectionid) seems to cause a Client Disconnect.

In what scenarios does Groups.Add cause a client disconnect - we also only seem to be experiencing this on Windows Phone.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can it be because the GET request is getting to big? https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3408

Comment: I think this looks exactly like my issue thanks Pawel